# How to insert multiple tiles in an object layer?

Tags: tiled

Currently I have set to have things snapped to grid automatically. I can insert tiles in an object layer by clicking around on the grid. The problem is that I can only place each of those tiles one by one - clicking on each grid slot separately.

I would like to insert several of those tiles in an object layer by holding down the mouse button and dragging around the grid, similarly to how ordinary tiles are placed on a tile layer. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Currently (as of Tiled 1.4.1) there is no built-in tool to do this.

If you really need this functionality, you can consider [implementing a custom script](https://doc.mapeditor.org/en/stable/reference/scripting/) that adds a tool that does just this. You can find an example scripted tool that inserts rectangle objects here:

https://github.com/mapeditor/tiled-extensions/blob/master/rectangle-chain.js

To change it to insert tile objects, you'd just need to set the `object.tile` property to the desired tile. You could get the tile from the currently selected brush, say just taking the top-left one:

```js
const brush = tiled.mapEditor.currentBrush.layerAt(0)
const tile = brush.tileAt(0, 0)

var object = new MapObject(MapObject.Rectangle, ++this.counter)
object.tile = tile
object.x = x
object.y = y
object.width = tile.width
object.height = tile.height
```

You'll still want to add the snapping to the grid as well of course. And you could even support placing multiple objects at once next to each other when a bigger tile stamp is selected. This is your tool now. :-)